# UIViewController.swift isn't working? Xcode/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a quiz app using an online tutorial that I found on youtube. So on the video the first "scene" they used was the quiz part but for me, I am using an introduction first with an opening page, a topics page and then the quiz. So, on the tutorial, when they create an outlet for the label, they connect it to `UIViewController.swift` while for me, since it is not the first scene, it automatically connects to `UIViewController.h`, which is much different from `UIViewController.swift` and I am not allowed to edit that since I don't own it. What do I do?
Also if I do use `UIViewController.h`, where do I insert the outlet since it is different from the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you created your project, you selected to use Objective-C instead of Swift. Create a new project and select **Swift as the language**.

---

[image]